# set Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit for Multipart upload with Retrofit

Tags: android, multipartform-data, retrofit

I'm working with a multipart upload. I used Retrofit and here is my interface:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST (EndPoint.SEND_MMS)
    void sendMMS(@Part("text") String text,@Part("attachments") TypedFile attachment, Callback<Object> callback);
```

part "text" and "attachments" has Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary. The server side cannot extract data from "text", it require Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit instead of binary.
Do you have any solution for my problem.

Regards,

Comment: Have you found a solution to configuring Content-Transfer-Encoding?

Comment: not yet, I have to request server side changing their solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Multipart
@POST (EndPoint.SEND_MMS)
void sendMMS(@Part(value = "text", encoding = "8bit") String text,@Part("attachments") TypedFile attachment, Callback<Object> callback);
```

*retrofit.http.Part* [javadoc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Part.html)